# Why does my google autocomplete just freeze then time out?

Tags: php

I am making a website that requires users to sign up (Free) and i have a location text input that i want to autocomplete exactly like the one on this site when signing up, however when I go to type in a location the field freezes on the first letter, then times out.
Here is my code

```
<input id="locay" name="location" type="text" size="50" required />
<br /><br />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key[MY_KEY]&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        var input = document.getElementById('locay');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

why is this not working?

Comment: I know it has to be simple but for some reason I am having a mind blank, thank you for your time

Comment: This question is too broad. Because there is a lot to do to achieve the correct answer. Back-end and Front-end code. Unless you show up some code that we can contribuite I think this question could be closed.

Comment: I changed the `key=[MY_KEY]&callback=initMap` with  `key=[MY_KEY].&sensor=false&libraries=places""></script> ` the text field now gets "enter location" but then wont load when try typing... just freezes, then I get a "Oops, something went wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All working now i finally changed it to `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.&libraries=places&key=[MY_KEY]"></script>` then went to my google API console and authorised my URL then ensured the Google maps javascript API was enabled now all is working.